# Why so many Parquet files created? Can we not limit Parquet output files?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, parquet

Why so many Parquet files created in sparkSql? Can we not limit Parquet output files ?

Comment: Please explain your question better. How are you creating the files? Please provide a complete minimal verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also please explain what exactly are you trying to do? Why is the number of files problematic? is there a goal number here? maybe the issue is with something else (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I have ETL job written in spark 1.6 we want to store translation data. our requirement is very simple we want to search a string from this parquet files (size approx more than 200GB, snappy). for writing we are using below code :
test.saveAsParquetFile(locationfile);
by using this method Parquet create lots of files, its easy to understand if we have lots of file so search will take time as IO will get increase. we need to perform some optimization techniq so that our search can perform better.

Answer (score 0):

in general when you write to parquet it will write one (or more depending on various options) files per partition. If you want to reduce the number of files you can call coalesce on the dataframe before writing. e.g.:

```
df.coalesce(20).write.parquet(filepath)
```

Of course if you have various options (e.g. partitionBy) the number of files can increase dramatically.

Also note that if you coalesce to a very small number of partitions this can become very slow (both because of copying data between the partitions and because of the reduced parallelism if you go to a number small enough). You might also get OOM errors if the data in a single partition is too large (when you coalesce the partitions naturally get bigger).

A couple of things to note:

- saveAsParquetFile is depracated since version 1.4.0. Use write.parquet(path) instead.
- Depending on your use case, searching for a specific string on parquet files might not be the most efficient way to go.

Comment: can anyone tell me what is the default Raw Group size while writing the parquetfile using SparkSql ?